# How can I create more instances of same object in C#?

Tags: c#, object, copying

There is a simple code:

```
class Test
{
    public int number;
    public void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Test obj=new Test();
            obj.number=3;
        }           
    }
}
```

This program sets the "number" of obj to 3 in every moment. But I would like to create a totally another, unique object with copy of content of the original object in every loop, automatically. If I make an object with same name, it will be overwritten.
Naturally I don't want to use it in an endless loop, it would be meaningless, but it was the easiest way to explain my problem.

Comment: You are Creating new Object in every loop, becouse of the block scope, every loop you create an object with `obj` variable, and destroy it end of the loop, and re create it in the next tick...

Comment: Why are you asking this question? That may help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new objects each iteration, but you only keep reference to the last created object.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myOjects = new List<Test>();

    int startIndex = 1;

    while(true)
    {
        Test obj=new Test();
        obj.number=startIndex;

        myObjects.Add(obj);

        startIndex = startIndex + 1;

        if (startIndex > 5) break;
    }           
}
```

Now you can go through all objects in your list:

```
foreach (var obj in myObjects) obj.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you can do this.

My first thought would be to use a factory method (it just returns an instance of a class). It would look something like this.

```
public Test TestFactory()
{
    return new Test() { number = 3 };
}
```

Or add a constructor to the Test class that takes an instance of Test:

```
// inside Test class
public Test(Test that)
{
    number = that.number;
}
```